# PostGIS update data with ST_Tile

Tags: raster, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I need to update tiled raster data from the "whole image". I have created this query:

```
UPDATE data_tiled AS t  SET raw_data = f.raw_data  
FROM 
( 
SELECT data_time, data_type, ST_Tile(raw_data, 250, 250) As raw_data  
FROM data_full 
WHERE data_time = '2015-12-06 00:00:00' AND data_type = 'a' 
) as f 
WHERE t.data_time = f.data_time AND t.data_type = f.data_type;
```

but this will result in one tile copied to every row. For example, source is tiled to 18 rasters, 18 rows is updated, but every row has the same content. I need it to be each row its own tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it this way:

```
UPDATE data_tiled t 
SET raw_data = f.raw_data_tile
FROM 
( 
  SELECT data_time, data_type, ST_Tile(raw_data, 250, 250) As raw_data_tile  
  FROM data_full  
  WHERE data_time = '2015-12-06 00:00:00' AND data_type = 'a' 
) as f 
WHERE t.data_time = f.data_time 
AND t.data_type = f.data_type
AND ST_UpperLeftX(t.raw_data) = ST_UpperLeftX(f.raw_data_tile)
AND ST_UpperLeftY(t.raw_data) = ST_UpperLeftY(f.raw_data_tile)
```